# Count number of rows which have at least two positive answers in range of few columns

Tags: mysql

I have a example database. How to count number of rows which have at least two positive answers in range a1a-a1d? 1-positive, 2- negative

[image]

Comment: which sql are you using ?

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: does the solution below works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
id,
count (case 
           when (
                 (a1a > 0 and a1b > 0)  or (a1a > 0 and a1c > 0)
              or (a1a > 0 and a1d > 0)  or (a1b > 0 and a1c > 0)
              or (a1b > 0 and a1d > 0)  or (a1c > 0 and a1d > 0)
                                                                  )
           then 1 else 0 end as total

from [table name]
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL treats booleans as integers, so you can use:

```
select t.*,
       (a1a > 0) + (a1b > 0) + (a1c > 0) + (a1d > 0) as num_positive
from t;
```

For a count, move this to the `where` clause:

```
select count(*)
from t
where ( (a1a > 0) + (a1b > 0) + (a1c > 0) + (a1d > 0) ) > 2;
```

Note:  Your data only has values for `1` and `2`.  You can use any threshold that you like.